# How can I fix the Scyther wx.splashscreen error?

Tags: python, wxpython, splash-screen

Having installed Scyther, along with Graphwiz and wxPython, I get the error:

```
File "scyther-gui.py", line 141, in <module>
class MySplashScreen(wx.SplashScreen):
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SplashScreen'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently arises because Scyther was written with an older version of wxPython.

I found that Thomas Fleming has updated it for more recent versions of wxPython (I have 4.0.7.post2), you can find his GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/Thomas-Fleming/scyther). It looks like it will be pulled into the main branch at some point, but at the moment I used his fork.
 The instructions in the readme are pretty clear and I followed them no problem, but for me the file `scyther-linux` wasn't automatically copied from `/src` to `/gui` so I had to move it manually.

His fix seems to work for people on mac too, however, I'm using Ubuntu 18.4 and although I got past the splashscreen error and Scyther loaded, I wasn't able to open files, getting

```
File "/home/weaver/tools/scyther-master/gui/Gui/Mainwindow.py", line 291, in OnOpen
    if self.askUserForFilename(style=wx.OPEN,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OPEN'
```

and equivalent for save.

To fix this I opened `/gui/Gui/Mainwindow.py`, and changed line 291 from

```
if self.askUserForFilename(style=wx.OPEN,
```

to

```
if self.askUserForFilename(style=wx.FD_OPEN,
```

and on line 302 did the same for `wx.SAVE`, changing it to `wx.FD_SAVE`.

So far things seem to be running fine.

Hope this helps.